# How to get all the fields after groupby in LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-group

I have this object

[image: result view]

[image: result view desglosed]

With Fecha="Julio2017" I have 2 items and I need to group these three items by SubcontratistaId and Fecha.

item1.Realizado=4060.000 and item2.Realizado=-4060.000 So I need to show in Julio2017 the value of 0

So I try this

```
private IEnumerable<SubcontratacionesEnFecha> GetRealizadosEnFecha(string proyectoId)
.....   
return realizadosAbonadosEnFechaAcumulados
   .GroupBy(x => new { x.SubcontratistaId, x.Fecha })
```

But now I don't know how to get the values of all the items grouped

If I try this I get error
[image: error]

If I try this

```
return realizadosAbonadosEnFechaAcumulados
   .GroupBy(x => new { x.SubcontratistaId, x.Fecha })
   .Select(x=>x.First())
   .ToList();
```

I get this

[image: no agrupado con first]

That is, I get the first value of the items grouped

Any idea Please?

Thanks

Comment: `GroupBy(...).ToList()`. But for which purpose? This is the question.

Comment: [Please don't post code and results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines.

Comment: "So I need to show in Julio2017 the value of 0" - what does this mean in terms of _C# Code_? C# is a strongly type dependent language, what datatype do you want as a result of your query?

Answer (score 3):

`GroupBy` returns `IGrouping<,>`, which has Key and itself is `IEnumerable<>` of grouped items. So more probable usage is:

```cs
return realizadosAbonadosEnFechaAcumulados
   .GroupBy(x => new { x.SubcontratistaId, x.Fecha })
   .Select(g => new 
   { 
      g.Key.SubcontratistaId,
      g.Key.Fecha,
      Items = g.ToList()
   })
   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found this way

```
var agrupacion = from p in realizadosAbonadosEnFechaAcumulados
                   group p by new { p.SubcontratistaId, p.Fecha } into grupo
                   select grupo;

        foreach (var grupo in agrupacion)
        {
            foreach (var objetoAgrupado in grupo)
            {
              resultAgrupado.Add(new SubcontratacionesEnFecha
               {
                SubcontratistaId = objetoAgrupado.SubcontratistaId,
                NombreSubcontratista= objetoAgrupado.NombreSubcontratista,
                ProyectoId = objetoAgrupado.ProyectoId,
                Fecha = objetoAgrupado.Fecha,
                Mes = objetoAgrupado.Mes,
                Año = objetoAgrupado.Año,
                Realizado = objetoAgrupado.Realizado,
                Planificado = objetoAgrupado.Planificado
              });

             }
           } 

  return resultAgrupado;
```

Comment: Aren't you just un-grouping them there again?